# How can I implement a graceful restart an Azure Web App instance

Tags: azure, web-applications, application-restart

We have memory issue with our .NET application which is often working with really big strings. I wonder if I can somehow ask an Azure web app instance stop receiving new requests for a while before I can restart the instance. I've googled around but I could only see how to warm up an instance gracefully.

Comment: AFAIK, you could put a `app_offline.htm` file into the root of your web app folder (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`) to make your web app offline, then your web app would stop receiving new requests. Why don't you forcibly restart your web app instance? Are you worry about losing the data? Have you considered to store your big strings outside of your web app?

Comment: Hi @BruceChen, I do not want to terminate on-going and pending requests. I did try to use JavascriptServices to handle string operation but the performance is much slower. I'd like your trick. I will try and let you know the result. Thanks a lot